# Passing a variable instead of a file/filepath to getJson

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm creating dynamic dropdown lists from values in my database. I'm querying the data, creating a php variable in this format:

```
$items = array(
   'red'=>'apples,firetrucks,blood',
   'yellow'=>'bus,pencil,duck'
);
```

I can then use the `json_encode()` function to encode.

```
{
  "red":"apples,firetrucks,blood",
  "yellow":"bus,pencil,duck",
}
```

I know the `getJson` is passed at file or a path like:

```
$.getJSON("jsondata/data.json", function(data) {
```

Can my json variable be passed to this function instead? The reason I want a variable to be passed, rather than a file is because my data can chance on a daily basis, ie:

```
$items = array(
   'red'=>'apples,firetrucks,bricks',
   'yellow'=>'bus,pencil,duck'
);
```

Comment: What? To start off, there is no such thing as a "JSON object". You either have a JSON string or a JS object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a PHP file that outputs the JSON you want;

In **/foo.php**:

```
echo json_encode(array(
    "red" => "apples,firetrucks,blood",
    "yellow" => "bus,pencil,duck",
));
```

... then your JavaScript should make an AJAX request to `foo.php` using `getJSON`;

```
$.getJSON("/foo.php", function (data) {
    alert(data.red); // shows "apples,firetrucks,blood
    alert(data.yellow); // you get the idea
});
```

<sup>... It was so tempting to make the values for your object arrays, but I resisted... somehow</sup>

Comment: That is my problem, the values for `red` may change on a daily basis from `apples,firetrucks,blood` to `apples,firetrucks,bricks`.

Comment: ... so it's a good job that those are emitted by PHP, which can query the values from the database each time they're requested? Have you got your database query working to retrieve the daily values?

Comment: @etm124: You can iterate over them with jQuery.each or a for/in loop: `for (name in data) {  alert(name + ':' + data[name]); }` and with each `$.each(data, function (name, value) { alert(name + ':' + value);});`

Comment: @Matt, so you're saying, since I'm putting my `json_encode`d array in `foo.php`, the query will be run everytime the `.getJSON` function is called?

Comment: @etm124: Exactly... just be sure that your JavaScript uses `/foo.php` as the filename, rather than `jsondata/data.json`.